# Block Googlebots from fetching robots.txt on a microservice subdomain

Tags: seo, googlebot, crawl-errors

We have some microservices and as an example, Language Service's URL is the following;

```
http://prod-lang-service.example.com/
```

We have been getting errors (NotFoundException) on Rollbar that Google bots are calling this URL;

```
http://prod-lang-service.example.com/robots.txt
```

This is the Curl command;

```
curl --request GET 'http://prod-lang-service.example.com/robots.txt' \
--header 'cf-connecting-ip:66.249.66.34' \
--header 'accept-encoding:gzip' \
--header 'x-forwarded-port:443' \
--header 'x-forwarded-for:66.249.66.34, 172.70.174.230, 66.249.66.34' \
--header 'host:prod-lang-service.example.com' \
--header 'accept:text/plain,text/html,*/*' \
--header 'user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' \
--header 'x-amzn-trace-id:Root=1-6525fb3c-1626d9360cb93e3825dae376' \
--header 'connection:upgrade' \
--header 'x-forwarded-proto:https' \
--header 'cdn-loop:cloudflare' \
--header 'cf-visitor:{"scheme":"https"}' \
--header 'cf-ray:814359dad9149c48-IAD' \
--header 'cf-ipcountry:US'
```

Should I block this and other microservice URLs from `robots.txt` from `www.example.com/robots.txt`?

Comment: Is that curl command how you are emulating the exact headers that Googlebot is sending?

Comment: It sounds like you are proposing using `robots.txt` on your main domain to block URLs on a sub-domain.  However, that isn't possible.  Why wouldn't you just create a `robots.txt` file on the sub-domain?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks we will proceed creating sub-domain level robots.txt and disallow there. Cheers!